# Use a Timer or MediaPlayer method?

Tags: android, timer, media-player, handler

I am currently calling the .getCurrentPosition a lot to get the current position of my MediaPlayer. This seems to slow down my UI a lot as I'm running animations. My question is that instead of calling that method over and over...would it be better to use a timer and display that, and just stop/start it on click?

Here is my current code:

> private void startTimer() {
>                 Thread promoThread = new Thread() {
>
> ```
>         @Override
>         public void run() {
>
>           while(media[1].isPlaying()){
>
>           Message msg = new Message(); 
>
>           String timer1 =
> ```
>
> getTimeString(media[1].getCurrentPosition());
>
> ```
>           msg.obj = timer1;
>
>           mHandler.sendMessage(msg); 
>
>           }
>
>         }
>
>
>     };
>     promoThread.start();
>       }
> ```

and:

> protected final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
>
> ```
>   @Override public void handleMessage(Message msg) { 
>
>       String text = (String)msg.obj;
>
>       myText.setText(text);
> }
> ```
>
> };

Comment: Thx for posting the question, I questioned it to myself this morning!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call getPosition all the time to track playing time, instead just fire that timer and update your UI according to timer time. You can put also an OnInfoListener() to MediaPlayer to track end of play and kill timer.

Use runOnUiThread() inside Timer to update UI, no need of doing it with Handler.

I coded such a timer fired each 200mS and updated my counter UI with no problems at all.

Comment: do you think this way will slow down my animation at all?

Comment: I don't think so, Timer runs in its own thread, give it a try with 500mS or so. Do you need a fine grain counter?

Comment: I dont think so. There are similar apps out there to what I'm building with their counters updating with no delay and with animations running smooth. That is what confuses me.

Comment: If you need such performance, you should think to move that part of your code to NDK in C++, not java.

Comment: He does not need to code it in the NDK.  In case anyone else comes across this, it's seems pretty obvious to me his problem is that he just has it in a while() block with no sleeps.  He could put basically anything within, and it would make the UI stutter because it is continually running as fast as it can.